# KeyPress is acting weird, but button click is doing fine VB.net

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio

I'm using the code below to do a search in my database but my keypress is acting weird.

```
Private Sub txtSearch4_KeyPress(sender As Object, e As KeyPressEventArgs) Handles txtSearch4.KeyPress
   Call btnSearch4_Click(sender, e)
End Sub

Private Sub btnSearch4_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnSearch4.Click
    If SQL.HasConnection = True Then
        SQL.ExecQuery("SELECT Customer, Product, Part_Number FROM Product WHERE (" & cmbType4.Text & " LIKE '%" & txtSearch4.Text & "%') ORDER BY Part_Number ASC")

        If SQL.DBDS.Tables.Count > 0 Then
            dgvProd.DataSource = SQL.DBDS.Tables(0)
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Video: https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B7BUg5POgN7dZGVBTUpad1FWdDg
As you can see in the video, when I press a key it doesn't fire up right away. I want it this way, when I press a single key, it will auto fire like how you press a button.
Thanks guys.

Comment: You should never call an event handler directly like that.  You should either be calling the `PerformClick` method of the `Button` or else put the code in its own method and call that from both event handlers.  Also, that use of the `Call` keyword is pointless.

Comment: @jmcilhinneyI tried putting the whole code in KeyDown and KeyPress and doing the same thing. Even tried performclick and it's the same.

Comment: I'm talking about writing code properly, not solving your problem, which is why I posted a comment rather than an answer.

Comment: @jmcilhinney either, it's doing the same thing. :D

Comment: @jmcilhinney: Though your remark makes much sense, it does not addresses the root cause of the problem.
Your second comment voids what I just wrote! :-)

Answer (score 1):

Use the KeyDown event instead. This event is raised as soon as you press a key on the keyboard whereas KeyPress event is raised for character keys while the key is pressed and THEN released by the user.

```
Private Sub txtSearch4_KeyDown(sender As Object, e As KeyPressEventArgs) Handles txtSearch4.KeyDown
   doSearch()
End Sub

Private Sub btnSearch4_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnSearch4.Click
   doSearch()
End Sub

Private Sub doSearch()
    If SQL.HasConnection = True Then
        SQL.ExecQuery("SELECT Customer, Product, Part_Number FROM Product WHERE (" & cmbType4.Text & " LIKE '%" & txtSearch4.Text & "%') ORDER BY Part_Number ASC")

        If SQL.DBDS.Tables.Count > 0 Then
            dgvProd.DataSource = SQL.DBDS.Tables(0)
        End If
    End If
end sub
```

Comment: I used the KeyDown and doing the same. As you can see in the video, KeyDown doesn't react when I pressed the first e.
https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B7BUg5POgN7dNmxoTXhzYjhmWHM

Comment: For some reason the video did now show anything.
Before doing further investigations, I 'd suggest to avoid calling the Click event directly, as pointed out by @jmcilhinney.

I have edited my answer for show how your code should look like. Though it's not directly addressing the issue, it may help 
to sort it out by placing a break point in the doSearch procedure in order to verify when it is called.

Comment: We don't need a video that we can't actually see. Did you place a breakpoint on the code to see whether it got hit when you depressed a key?  If not, do so.

Comment: Actually, you should probably use the KeyUp event, not down.

Comment: @Jeroen: As the initial intend is to get a reaction immediately when a key get pressed, KeyDown is the actual event to use. 

KeyUp is fired only when the key is released, just as KeyPressed so it would not satisfy the requested behavior.

Comment: "And then the customer said, with a taunt and a smile, that is exactly what I asked for, but not what I wanted." It's a bad idea in this use case to use KeyDown. Yup, it's what the OP asked for, but he is using the `TextBox` value in the subsequent query, and so that query will fire BEFORE the user is done typing. I have spoken to enough users to know that is considered unexpected behaviour. :-)

Comment: @Jeroen: Very valid point! I took the problem out of its context, You are right : within that specific context, KeyUp would be a better option.